# Why can't I pass this to Array.prototype.filter function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) Array.prototype.filter could receive a second parameter which serves as a

> Value to use as this when executing callback.

However, when I try to pass a second argument, it ignores it, and `this` points to the window object. For example:

```
const iFilter = (val, i) => {
    console.log(this)    // Prints the window object. 
    ......
}

const someObj = {...}
console.log( ["a","b","c","d"].filter(iFilter, someObj))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you miss the part of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and their `this` handling.

Comment: @NinaScholz, Thanks! I understand. Though reading the other thread points to the solution, I am not sure this is a duplicate. The other question asks what does `this` refer to in an arrow function compared to a regular function. The current question goes one step further - not only that this is determined statically in an arrow function, it's not possible to bind a different value to it.

Comment: *"it's not possible to bind a different value to it"* @BenCarp, No. arrow functions **don't have** `this` or `arguments`. The variable/value you're referencing is just a closure of the value from outside the arrow function. So it desn't matter how you try to pass/bind `this`, arrow functions simply don't have this "property".